# Why SSISDeploy overwrite the whole projects and not only what was modified?

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, ssis

I have the below structure in `ssis` server:

[image: ssis]

Assuming I worked on `Integration service` project in `VS` but only on one `dtsx` from the list above.
Now I ran the below `SSISDeploy` (documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15#ssisdeployexe)) command from `CMD`:

```
SSISDeploy.exe -s:"C:\git\test\Integration Services\bin\Development\Integration Services.ispac" -d:catalog;/SSISDB/TEST/TEST_INRG;"TEST03,1234" -at:win
```

and got this message:

> Will deploy 'Integration Services.ispac' to TEST03,2890:/SSISDB/TEST/TEST_INTG. 
> The project 'TEST_INTG' already exists in the catalog folder 'TEST'. Will overwrite it.

So what actually happened, all the packages were delete and my `dtsx` package was overwritten the modified one. Is there a flag which can tell the command to change only what was modified? I was expecting to see only change in the actual `dtsx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got official answer in Microsoft forum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/441954/view.html